# How to delete the pod for one time task in kubernetes automatically?

Tags: kubernetes, busybox, minikube

In order to check status, I started the `busybox` in kubernetes using interactive shell.

```
$ kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh
/ # exit
$ kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh
Error from server (AlreadyExists): pods "busybox" already exists
```

When I exit from the shell, I expect the pod will be deleted as well. While it exists there in completed status.

```
$ kubectl get pods -a
NAME                     READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
busybox                  0/1       Completed   0          58m
```

I have to delete the pod, it is annoying.

DO we have simple parameter I can use to ask k8s to delete the pod for this one task job ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just add `--rm`:

```
$ kubectl run busybox -i --tty --image=busybox --restart=Never --rm -- sh
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # exit
$ kubectl get pod busybox
Error from server (NotFound): pods "busybox" not found
```

> `--rm=false`: If true, delete resources created in this command for attached containers.

Comment: simple, I just can't find in the doc. Nice !!

Comment: Doesn't work for me with `kubectl` 1.22.1. But I found a workaround by using `KUBECTL_COMMAND_HEADERS=false`: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1098#issuecomment-929743957.